# Python Decorator with extraneous arguments

Tags: python, decorator

I have a decorator that currently requires each function that uses it to have a few arguments, arg1, arg2, and arg3. It works fine.

But one of the args in particular feels extraneous in that the functions don't really want to have it as an input, e.g. for something like

```
@sql_decorator
def user_records(table, user, limit):
    "sql to select records from ' + table + ' with user=%s limit %s" % (user, limit)
```

user and limit make sense as inputs, but table does not because the caller never has control over that. It feels extraneous.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
@sql_decorator
def user_records(user, limit):
    "sql to select records from table with user=%s limit %s" % (user, limit)
```

and then have the decorator change the sql by finding the instance of table and changing it to the right value?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What does your decorator do? Do you want to write another function, or make `table` a keyword argument with a default value?

Comment: I hope you don't really build your SQL like that.  Your examples are vulnerable against SQL injections.

Comment: I don't get it, the examples you gave receive the same parameters.

Comment: apologies, the table arg in the second func made it unclear what I was trying. updated that. please let me know if it is still confusing. ... and no, this is just an example sql.

Comment: It is still confusing. Is **user_records** your decorator? What are you decorating it with? Can we see the code you currently have for both?

Comment: added that the decorator is different. What is the confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you have something like this:

```
def sql_decorator(func):
    def decorated(table, user, limit):
        ... # do stuff with table
        return func(table, user, limit)
    return decorated

@sql_decorator
def user_records(table, user, limit):
    ...
```

<strike>If so, then this is probably what you want:</strike> **No, wrong answer. See below.**

```
def sql_decorator(table_name):
    def the_actual_decorator(func):
        def decorated(user, limit):
            ... # do stuff with table_name
            return func(user, limit)
        return decorated
    return the_actual_decorator

@sql_decorator('some_table_name')
def user_records(user, limit):
    ...
```

[edit] According to your comment you probably want something like this:

```
def sql_decorator(func):
    def decorated(user, limit):
        table = compute_the_table_somehow(user)
        return func(table, user, limit)
    return decorated

@sql_decorator
def user_records(table, user, limit):
    "sql to select records from %s with user=%s limit %s" % (table, user, limit)

data = user_records('joe', 100)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right because you are still just giving input to the @sql_decorator of the table_name, in this case 'some_table_name'. The decorator's job is to go find what table should be and then run the function with that value. The function only wants to give input of user and limit. It doesn't want to have 'table' as an arg, but I can't find a way to do this without having 'table' as an arg.

Comment: interesting. Will try this out and report back. Thanks.